Get parent element that contains string
I'm trying to get the class name of the div element that contains the information the calling areas between many div elements in the url. Since the div that contains the calling area information has USA states names, I'm using one state name as anchor to identify the div
This is my current code (Add Reference: Tools->Reference and check "Microsoft XML, v3.0")
Public Sub Main()
Dim url As String
Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim divs As IHTMLElementCollection, div As HTMLDivElement
    
    
    url = "https://www.rebtel.com/en/international-calling-guide/phone-codes/us/"
    oHttp.Open "GET", url, False
    oHttp.send
    
    Dim html As New HtmlDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = oHttp.responseText

    Set divs = html.body.getElementsByTagName("div")
    
    For Each div In divs
        If div.innerHTML Like "*Alabama*" Then
            Debug.Print div.className
        End If
    Next div
    

End Sub

And current output has several divs that contains string "Alabama", since this site contains nested divs and one div could contain string "Alabama" and their children too.
content-wrapper
codes_show_view
container
row gap-l
gap-xl-bottom gap-l-top
pull-left
pull-left
pull-left
pull-left

Where my desired output would be the div with classname = gap-xl-bottom gap-l-top
The how to identify the specific div that contains the calling area codes classname = gap-xl-bottom gap-l-top?

It's not clear what the problem is. Didn't you already find the div you needed?

My issue is that currently I'm getting several classnames as output, I'd stuck in how to identify the specific div that contains the calling area codes. Since there are nested divs and one parent div contains string Alabama and the child div too.

If div.className = "gap-xl-bottom gap-l-top" Then that's the one?  You can nest that inside If div.innerHTML Like "*Alabama*" Then

Yes. If I inspect the elements manually, I find the class="gap-xl-bottom gap-l-top". My issue resides in that I need to identify the specific div as if I didn't know the "Class name" since I want to apply the same code to other website too that has similar structure but different class name. I hope make sense

You could do this, but I don't see how it can generalize to a different site...
Public Sub Main()
Dim url As String
Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim divs As IHTMLElementCollection, div As Object, pDiv As Object
    
    
    url = "https://www.rebtel.com/en/international-calling-guide/phone-codes/us/"
    oHttp.Open "GET", url, False
    oHttp.send
    
    Dim html As New HtmlDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = oHttp.responseText

    Set divs = html.body.getElementsByTagName("div")
    
    For Each div In divs
        If div.innerHTML Like "*Alabama*" And div.className = "pull-left" Then
            Set pDiv = div.parentElement.parentElement 'the element two levels up in the DOM tree
            Debug.Print pDiv.className  '>> gap-xl-bottom gap-l-top
            Exit For
        End If
    Next div
End Sub


Thanks for the example. I see that is complicated because for example the other site has the div with the states list but inside the div there is a structure of <ul> and <li> for each state like this `
Select state.

Alabama

`
Yep - every site is different: you need a separate approach for each site.
